# Is there any way to remove RichTextBoxFormatBar from RichTextBox? (Extended WPF ToolKit)

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox, wpftoolkit

There are few `RichTextBox`es (not standard but from the Extended WPF Toolkit) in my window. I want to use a single `RichTextFormatBar` for all of them, attaching it to currently focused `RichTextBox`. First time it gets attached easily after calling `SetFormatBar` static method of `RichTextBoxFormatBarManager` class. But further attempts to attach the bar to a different `RichTextBox` cause exception with message "the control already has the parent". I can't find any method like `RemoveFormatBar` in the Manager. `FormatBar` has property Target, that should point to it's owner, but changing it by assignment doesn't give any results.

What can you suggest? (Except of an obvious variant - to use individual `FormatBar` for each `RichTextBox`).

Comment: Have you tried to use `SetFormatBar(null)` to detach the bar from the Richtextbox?